# How to find $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin y}{\sqrt{\sin y+c}}\ \text{d}y$?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is related to my previous asked question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26303/how-to-find-int-dd-fracz2-sqrtzc-cdot-sqrtd2-z2-dz). The integration can be simplified as (As pointed out by  Sivaram, the integral diverges to $-\infty$ as $c\to1+$):

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin y}{\sqrt{\sin y+c}}\ \text{d}y,\ \  c>1.$$

I am appreciated if there is a specific answer (it would be great if there are some details).

Thanks!

Comment: For $c=1$, the integral diverges. You might want to change it to $c>1$

Comment: Really? I believe that $c=1$ is the easiest case to compute and converges to 2.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+sin(x)/sqrt(sin(x)%2B1)+from+x+%3D+-pi/2+to+pi/2

Comment: Sorry I must be wrong. It should always negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using formula 288.03 in [Byrd and Friedman's handbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=W6GV17SP0kQC):

$$\int_{\varphi}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^m u}{\sqrt{a+b\sin\;u}}\mathrm du=\frac2{\sqrt{a+b}}\int_0^{F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin\;\varphi}{2}}\right)\mid\frac{2b}{a+b}\right)}\left(1-2\mathrm{sn}^2\left(u\mid\frac{2b}{a+b}\right)\right)^m\mathrm du$$

for $a > b > 0$, where $F(\phi|m)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind and $\mathrm{sn}(u|m)$ is a Jacobian elliptic function, we have

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin y}{\sqrt{\sin y+c}}\mathrm{d}y=2\left(\sqrt{1+c}\;E\left(\frac2{1+c}\right)-\frac{c}{\sqrt{1+c}}K\left(\frac2{1+c}\right)\right)$$

where $K(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, and $E(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.